# Error just on host, not on my computer; String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, host

I am in bad situation. I have a program that it works very well in my computer but when I upload it on the host it gives me this error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." my program is on ASP.net C# visual studio 2015

> Edit:
>   both date's format on my computer and on the host are the same. like
>   this:"mm/dd/yyyy"

would you please help me?
here is my code:
HTML:

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/mainMembers/frameMembers.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GMList.aspx.cs" Inherits="Federation.mainMembers.GMList" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainFrame" runat="server">
    <form id="gml" runat="server" method="post">
        <asp:Label ID="titr" runat="server" CssClass="shekaste" Text="title"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
         <div  runat="server"  style="height: 400px; width:800px; overflow: scroll">
        <asp:GridView ID="fedList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="parastoo" OnRowDataBound="MatchList_RowDataBound" >
            <Columns>
                
                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="a" DataField="birthday" />
                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="b" DataField="start_sport" />
                
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="c" DataField="ToDate" />
               
                
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </form>
</asp:Content>
```

2. C# code:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Web;
   using System.Web.UI;
   using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
   using System.Data.SqlClient;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Configuration;
   using System.Globalization;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
   using System.IO;

   namespace Federation.mainMembers
   {

       public partial class GMList : System.Web.UI.Page
       {
           SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NSG"].ConnectionString);
           //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
           DataSet ds = new DataSet();
           //private string strSQL;
           private SqlCommand com;
           SqlDataAdapter sda;
           // DateTime dtime;
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
           //DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
           PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
           //string memberID = "1111111112";
           string matchID = "";
           Boolean[] age2 = new Boolean[6];
           Boolean[] weight = new Boolean[9];
           //Int16 morshedi = 0;
           byte[] img1 = new byte[0];

           Int16 level;
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
               if (Session["FID"] != null)
               {
                   matchID = this.Session["FID"].ToString();
                   //memberID = this.Session["VID"].ToString();
                   //morshedi = Convert.ToInt16(this.Session["VMID"].ToString());

                   //string s;

                   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                   {


                       //********************************************************
                       dt.Rows.Clear();
                       con.Close();
                       sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select birthday,start_sport,ToDate   from general_members ", con);
                       con.Close();

                       con.Open();
                       dt.Rows.Clear();
                       sda.Fill(dt);

                       con.Close();
                       //string dds=dt.Rows[0]["ToDate"].ToString();
                       DataView dv1 = new DataView(dt);

                       fedList.DataSource = dv1;

                       fedList.DataBind();


                   }
               }
               else
               {
                   Response.Redirect("~/a.aspx");
               }


           }

           protected void MatchList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
           {
               if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
               {
                   // Find the value in the c04_oprogrs column. You'll have to use
                   // some trial and error here to find the right control. The line
                   // below may provide the desired value but I'm not entirely sure.

                   TableCell statusCell1 = e.Row.Cells[0];
                   TableCell statusCell2 = e.Row.Cells[1];
                   TableCell statusCell3 = e.Row.Cells[2];

                   string dstr = "";
                   int year, month, day;
                   year = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetYear(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
                   month = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
                   day = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
                   dstr = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString();
                   statusCell1.Text = dstr;

                   year = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetYear(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell2.Text)));
                   month = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell2.Text)));
                   day = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell2.Text)));
                   dstr = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString();
                   statusCell2.Text = dstr;

                   year = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetYear(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell3.Text)));
                   month = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell3.Text)));
                   day = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell3.Text)));
                   dstr = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString();
                   statusCell3.Text = dstr;


               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Please exclude unnecessary code, be specific

Comment: Seems you have problem with `Convert.ToDateTime`. Can you reduce provided code to be more specific & mention the line which throwing error? Also check date formatting on both development & production machine - ensure they're using same format.

Comment: So you have a Date-string in your `statusCellX` cells. Then you convert it to `DateTime` 3 times, extract a portion of it, just to join them together in another format instead of calling `.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")` in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is very likely different regional settings on your host.

To address this ensure you pass the expected CultureInfo to your conversion method:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx

See below, applied to your code. You will need to substitute the relevant culture string in the CultureInfo constructor:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");

year = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetYear(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text,culture)));
month = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text,culture)));
day = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text,culture)));
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17925094)

Comment: If you do as @Mikhail_Sam recommends, then I will vote not to delete.

Comment: @mikep . Agree - have updated as relevant to OP's question

Comment: I don't seem to get this in my review queue, so I hope SO has a mechanism for this.  Answer looks good.

Comment: thank you. but the program still gives me that error. I don't know why. I tried a lot without any result.

Comment: Did you pass the CultureInfo instance to all the convert calls? I only modified the ones related to statusCell1, but you have several others.

Comment: both date's format on my computer and on the host are the same. like this:"yyyy/dd/mm".

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that in the `c#` part of your code, you're using the [`Convert.ToDateTime(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhz1w05e(v=vs.110).aspx) overload. If you're using that, then the string you passed is converted using the regional settings of the machine you run this code on. Thus, the most likely cause is that the regional settings of your local machine and the host machine are different.

There's two things you can try:

1. Change the regional settings on your machine to what it is on the host. Most likely the error will then appear on your local system too.
2. Try to use the overload [`Convert.ToDateTime(string, IFormatProvider)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xk1h71t(v=vs.110).aspx). This will ensure that the conversion is always performed in the same way, regardless of your local settings.

Comment: thank you. but the program gives me that error. I don't know why. I tried a lot without any result.

Comment: both date's format on my computer and on the host are the same. like this:"yyyy/dd/mm"

Answer (score 0):

If your data returned from Sql is DateTime (datatype is datetime) then you can directly format date in your Gridview for date columns as below:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Birth Date" DataField="birthday" DataFormatString="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}" HtmlEncode="false" >
```

and delete your below code from RowDataBound event for all date columns

```
            int year, month, day;
            year = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetYear(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
            month = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
            day = Convert.ToInt32(pc.GetDayOfMonth(Convert.ToDateTime(statusCell1.Text)));
            dstr = year.ToString() + "/" + month.ToString() + "/" + day.ToString();
            statusCell1.Text = dstr;
```

Comment: I have to show the date in Persian calendar. so I have to use that code.

Comment: ok. can you put breakpoint and tell what value you get in statusCell1, statusCell2 and statusCell3 after lines TableCell statusCell1 = e.Row.Cells[0]; TableCell statusCell2 = e.Row.Cells[1]; TableCell statusCell3 = e.Row.Cells[2];